# bind second ddl depending on the first ddl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jquery, razor

I have a page where I have a `LeagueDDL`, a `ClubDDL` and then a list of players.  What I want to achieve is that the user will choose the League, after that the Clubs are bound to the second DDL according to the ID of the League, and when the user also chooses the Club, a list of players are bound to the View depending on the ClubID.

So far I have the following :-

View :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function populateClubsDropdown() {
    $("#ddlClubs").empty();
    var typeID = getLeagueID();
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetClubsByLeague", "Footballer")?TypeID=' + typeID, function (result) {
        $.each(result, function () {
            $("<option>").attr("value", this.ClubID).text(this.Club).appendTo("#ddlClubs");
        });
    });
}

function getLeagueID() {
    var leagueID = $("#ddlLeagues").val();
    return leagueID;
}

</script>


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList, 
    new { id = "ddlLeagues", onChange = "$:populateClubsDropdown()" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Club.ClubID, Model.ClubList, new { id = "ddlClubs" })
```

and in my controller I have :-

```
        public ViewResult Index()
    {
        League league = new League();
        string selected = "Please Select";
        model.LeagueList = model.PopulateLeagueDDL(selected, league, null);

        Club club = new Club();
        model.ClubList = model.PopulateClubDDL(selected, league, club, null);

        model.Footballers = db.Footballers.Include("Club").Include("Position").Include("Status").Include("Country");
        return View(model);
    }

       public JsonResult GetClubsByLeague(int LeagueID)
    {
        var result = footballersDAL.GetClubsByLeagueId(LeagueID).Select(
                c => new { ClubID = c.ClubID, Club = c.ClubName });
        JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

When I launch the page the first time, both Dropdowns are correct, however when I change the `LeagueDDL`, I get an empty second DDL. And the Json breakpoint is not being hit.

I would appreciate some help on this, I can't quite figure out what I have wrong.

UPDATE TO VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function populateClubsDropdown() {
    $("#ddlClubs").empty();
    var typeID = getLeagueID();
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetClubsByLeague", "Footballer")?TypeID=' + typeID, function (result) {
        $.each(result, function () {
            $("<option>").attr("value", this.ClubID).text(this.Club).appendTo("#ddlClubs");
        });
    });
}

function getLeagueID() {
    var leagueID = $("#ddlLeagues").val();
    return leagueID;

$(function () {
        $('#ddlLeagues').change(populateClubsDropdown);
    });
}
```

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList,
            new { id = "ddlLeagues" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Club.ClubID, Model.ClubList, new { id = "ddlClubs" })
```

Comment: does `populateClubsDropdown` being called onchange? try put an alert there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList, 
new { id = "ddlLeagues", onChange="$:populateClubsDropdown()" }) //What is"$:"?!
```

Change to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList, 
new { id = "ddlLeagues", onChange = "populateClubsDropdown()" })
```

Usage of jQuery unobtrusive event listener is event better:

```
 <script>    
    function populateClubsDropdown() {
        $("#ddlClubs").empty();
        var typeID = getLeagueID();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetClubsByLeague", "Footballer")?TypeID=' + typeID, function (result) {
            $.each(result, function () {
                $("<option>").attr("value", this.ClubID).text(this.Club).appendTo("#ddlClubs");
            });
        });
    }

    $(function(){
        $('#ddlLeagues').change(populateClubsDropdown);
    });
</script>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList, 
new { id = "ddlLeagues"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Club.ClubID, Model.ClubList,
 new { id = "ddlClubs" })
```

---

**Update:**
It's looks like you send the wrong parameter to the action:
should be `LeagueID` but you send `TypeId`~

Comment: tried onChange = "populateClubsDropdown()" did not work.  How can I implement the second one?  Tried replacing the jquery one with the onChange = "populateClubsDropdown()" but got an error

Comment: @Johann. what error? make sure the function declared above this code.

Comment: this did not work either onChange = "$('#ddlLeagues').change(populateClubsDropdown);"

Comment: changed to this now :-  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.League.LeagueID, Model.LeagueList,
                new { id = "ddlLeagues", onChange = "$('#ddlLeagues').change(populateClubsDropdown);" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Club.ClubID, Model.ClubList, new { id = "ddlClubs" })
but still did not populate the dropdownlists and also did not step into the code

Comment: @Johann. =). This is not the way it should be. Write that code inside `<script>` tag. and remove the `onChange` from the HTML attributes...

Comment: Hi gdoron, yes I am very new to Jquery, I mean basic knowledge.  I have updated my question with the new code in the view, but still cannot get the populated DDL's :(

Comment: gdoron I have update my View to implement your code but I still cannot get the 2nd DDL to populate correctly :(

Comment: @Johann.You are sending the wrong parameter.See my update. test your code with alerts and firebug.

Comment: oh Shhhooottt.  Sorry gdoron, could not see the easiest of mistakes.  Changing the TypeID did it.  So now I guess I have to do the same to get the players from that club right?

Comment: @Johann. make sure you attach the change handler right, give it the right param (accept my excellent answer) and you are done... **=) lol**

Comment: hahah ok, if I do not manage I will post back, but yes it was an excellent answer :)  Thanks mate